# Docker can't find reference from a private repository

Tags: docker

At my company, we have a Nexus 3 repository at address https://10.X.X.100/nexus3. [Docker documents](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/pushing-images) says we have to do this:

```
docker tag <imageId or imageName> <nexus-hostname>:<repository-port>/<image>:<tag>
docker tag af340544ed62 nexus.example.com:18444/hello-world:mytag
```

But as I have a slash ('/') in my hostname, I think it is recognizing nexus3 as my image instead of server. So tag is created:

```
docker tag <imageId> http://10.X.X.100/nexus3:18079/myimage:latest
```

But it returns this error to me

```
 Error parsing reference: "http://10.X.X.100/nexus3:18079/myimage:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

PS: I removed *http://* but the error is the same.

I didn't find an example with this situation or if it's possible.

Do you guys know anyhow to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove http:// from the URL.

```
docker tag <imageId> 10.X.X.100/nexus3:18079/myimage:latest
```

Comment: yea, i tried with http and without http. let me edit the question with this point. thank you!

Comment: yea, it's connecting as it should. if there's no way, i'll have to ask infrastructure to change this url lol